# why should the disparity value in sgbm be divisble by 16?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matching, digital

I am working on opencv sgbm(semi global block matching) function. Here two parameters (minDisparity and numberOfDisparities) are used.
In that why **numberOfDisparities** values should be divisible by 16?

Comment: Probably implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to simplify the code internally, which uses SSE2.  In general, SSE2 instructions:

- Work on multiple numbers simultaneously; having the total number of pieces of information be evenly divisible makes things simpler.
- SSE2 requires 128-bit (16 byte) memory alignment; alignment can be more easily maintained when things are nice multiples of 16...

If you examine the OpenCV source code, you'll see lots of SSE2 code for the SGBM algorithm.